# regex precceded by two or more special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am stuck with creating regex such that if the word is preceded or ended by special character more than one regex on each side regex 'exec' method should throw null. Only if word is wrap with exactly one bracket on each side 'exec' method should give result Below is the regular expression I have come up with.

If the string is like "(test)" or then only regex.exec should have values for other combination such as "((test))" OR "((test)" OR "(test))" it should  be null. Below code is not throwing null which it should. Please suggest.

```js
var w1 = "\(test\)"; 

alert(new RegExp('(^|[' + '\(\)' + '])(' + w1 + ')(?=[' + '\(\)'   + ']|$)', 'g').exec("this is ((test))"))
```

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB8cC9/2), is it what you are looking for?

Comment: stribizhe, you have provided me exact regex that meets my requirement which is find exact match depending on special char exactly one of each side. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I will post it then.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of words and want to filter them, you can do the following.

```
string.split(' ').filter(function(word) {
  return !(/^[!@#$%^&*()]{2,}.+/).test(word) || !(/[!@#$%^&*()]{2,}$).test(word)
});
```

The `split()` function splits a string at a space character and returns an array of words, which we can then `filter`.

To keep the valid words, we will test two regex expressions to see if the word starts or ends with 2 or more special characters respectively.

RegEx Breakdown

`^` - Expression starts with the following

`[]` - A single character in the block

`!@#$%^&*()` - These are the special characters I used. Replace them with the ones you want.

`{2,}` - Matches 2 or more of the preceeding characters

`.+` - Matches 1 or more of any character

`$` - Expression ends with the following

To use the `exec` function this way do this

```
!(/^[!@#$%^&*()]{2,}.+/).exec(string) || !(/[!@#$%^&*()]{2,}$).exec(string)
```

Comment: Thanks Richard (& Perez too!). Richard after the result from 'exec' method i have to replace and enclose the same word with span tag so I want one regex that matches word that has only one start & end tag with special characters such as "(". Your regex work goods but i want one expression. Also can you please use new Regex as I have use  because special character are causing issue when we use with dynamically in Regex variable due to additional escape character.

Comment: Richard your explanation is excellent for regex, it has really helped me understand regex with more clarity . Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for any string which contains `(test)`, anywhere in it, and exactly that, right?

In that case, what you probably need is the following:

```
var regExp = /.*[^)]\(test\)[^)].*/;

alert(regExp.exec("this is ((test))"));   // → null
alert(regExp.exec("this is (test))" ));   // → null
alert(regExp.exec("this is ((test)" ));   // → null

alert(regExp.exec("this is (test) ...")); // → ["this is (test) ..."]
```

Explanation:

`.* matches any character (except newline) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible.`

`[^)] match a single character but not the literal character )`

This makes sure there's your test string in the given string, but it is only ever wrapped with one brace in every side!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(^|[^(])(\(test\))(?!\))
```

See [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uB8cC9/2), replace with `$1<span style="new">$2</span>`.

The regex features an alternation group `(^|[^(])` that matches either start of string `^` or any character other than `(`. This alternation is a kind of a workaround since JS regex engine does not support look-behinds.

Then, `(\(test\))` matches and captures `(test)`. Note the round brackets are escaped. If they were not, they would be treated as a capturing group delimiters.

The `(?!\))` is a look-ahead that makes sure there is no literal `)` right after `test)`. Look-aheads are supported fully by JS regex engine.

A JS snippet:

```js
var re = /(^|[^(])(\(test\))(?!\))/gi; 
var str = 'this is (test)\nthis is ((test))\nthis is ((test)\nthis is (test))\nthis is ((test\nthis is test))';
var subst = '$1<span style="new">$2</span>'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
alert(result);
```

Comment: I have added an explanation now. When time allows, I will post a better snippet.